# Where to nap in Chicago O'Hare?

Tags: layovers, sleeping, chicago, lounges, ord

I am bracing myself for a rough trip: getting up at 4AM, taking a 3 hour flight, then a 13 hour flight, with a 5.5 hour layover in between.

I can almost never sleep on planes, so this trip would go down smoother if I could get a decent nap during the layover at Chicago O'Hare. What are my options?

I'd be particularly happy if there are any lounges I can pay my way into that have sleep rooms and/or showers.

EDIT: There are showers in one of the two AA Admirals' Clubs, according to [these](http://www.loungeguide.net/wiki/u/Chicago_%28ORD%29_American_Airlines_Admirals_Club_%28Concourses_H/K%29) [pages](http://www.lounges.net/Chicago-%28ORD%29-Airport-Lounges/). They also have cell-phone free quiet rooms. If anybody's been in them, I'd love to hear your opinion on how quiet they were, and whether they're good for naps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use those Admirals' Clubs regularly. They are OK. The food and drinks options are poor, but the showers are pretty nice. There are also some comfortable chairs which recline, which might be good for sleeping, although they can go quickly. The quiet rooms generally *are* quiet, but they don't contain the reclining chairs (from memory).

[It costs $50 for a day pass](http://www.aa.com/i18n/travelInformation/airportAmenities/admiralsClubArticles/oneDayPass.jsp&locale=es_ES), so you can decide if that's worth it to you.

Assuming you are in Terminal 3, it's also worth checking out the Virgin America gates along concourse L, which have powerports, and the new Mexican place near Gate K8 or so (best food in the terminal).

Answer (score 7):

I've not slept in this airport, so I can't give you personal information. Nevertheless there is a site called "Sleep in Airports" that gives general information about sleeping in almost any airport. About Chicago O'Hare, [this page](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/usa/chicago_ohare.htm) says that you can sleep in a lounge for US$40-50, there are 3 hotels and if you are looking for a free nap you have some reviews about where and how to do it.

Comment: This brings up two questions to my mind: Are private lounges that much nicer to sleep in, even if they don't have sleep rooms/showers? Also, I arrive in ORD at 8 AM. Would an airport hotel allow me to check in that early?

Comment: Hotels in airports or close to them typically allow 24-hour check-in (check the booking terms for clarifications regarding specific hotels).

Comment: @SuperElectric Large airports in the US don't close they just don't allow flights taking off between 11pm - 12am and either 5 or 6 am.  The hotels have 24 hour check in especially those in airports.  The only question is whether or not they will allow you to have a room for less then 1 night

Answer (score 7):

It's hard to find good info on spots in the airport, but [Foursquare](https://foursquare.com/v/chicago-ohare-international-airport-ord/4a5a77a4f964a52062ba1fe3) does mention:

> New privacy station with nice seats and power (free) near Johnny
>   Rockets between T1 & T2

if you're looking for a place to nap and recharge (pun intended), this may be it.

[Apparently](https://foursquare.com/v/chicago-ohare-international-airport-ord/4a5a77a4f964a52062ba1fe3), several of the departure gates also include arm-less benches (airport sleepers' dream!)

But possibly the [most useful](https://foursquare.com/v/chicago-ohare-international-airport-ord/4a5a77a4f964a52062ba1fe3) in terms of lounges, as you were asking:

> Did you know you can buy a one day pass at any United Club? The C
>   concourse location is pretty roomy, has a "quiet" room, decent wines,
>   clean bathrooms. And, means not waiting out a delay at the gate.