# Take a nap in the United Club in Chicago O'Hare?

Tags: layovers, sleeping, united-airlines, lounges, ord

I'm bracing myself for a rather long trip: a 3 hour flight, 8 hour layover, and then a 16 hour flight.  Also, I will be getting up around 4am that morning.  So it will be really helpful if I can find a place to take a nap.

[This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4720/where-to-nap-in-chicago-ohare) contains some information about AA Admirals club.  However, since I'm travelling with the United Airlines, I am thinking about purchasing a one-day-pass for the United Club (Terminal 1).  Will I be able to take a decent nap in the United Club?

Comment: There are no beds in the club, but there are very comfortable chairs there. (Even though you fly with United you can buy a one-day pass for AAdmirals Club or Delta Sky Club at ORD; but of course it's more convenient to use the United Club).

Comment: Airport hotel? Expensive, but a guaranteed bed.

Comment: @DJClayworth: I don't think ORD has a hotel inside the terminal, so this would mean taking a cab or shuttle to a hotel, and coming back in enough time to clear security.  That could make a big dent in nap time.

Comment: @NateEldredge: There is a Hilton hotel connected to the terminal at ORD. If you are willing to pay for the hotel, the only drawback is that you have to leave the secure area.

Comment: @R-traveler: I see, it doesn't seem to be marked on the terminal map.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Here is a link to hotel's web site: http://www3.hilton.com/en/hotels/illinois/hilton-chicago-ohare-airport-CHIOHHH/index.html . The hotel is connected to ORD terminals 1,2 and 3 by an underground tunnel. The same tunnel connects terminals to the subway station and parking garages. It's a very short walk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, Delta Sky Club, Admirals Club and United Club are comparable to each other. But I know that some travelers have strong preference toward one club or another. All of them are *much more* comfortable than publicly available halls: there are quiet rooms in the clubs, they offer snacks, drinks, and free wi-fi. However, they don't have beds.

At ORD, three main terminals are connected to each other on the airside. So you can go to any of these three lounges without leaving the secure area (the International Terminal is not connected to Terminals 1,2, and 3. But all domestic and most international flights by US carriers depart from Terminals 1, 2, and 3). United Club will be the most convenient for you: it will be the closest to your departure gate, United staff will inform you when the boarding starts and assist you if your flight is delayed.

As DJClayworth suggested, you can also book a room in the Hilton Airport Hotel. It is connected to Terminals 1,2 and 3 by an underground tunnel. (The same tunnel connects terminals to the subway station and parking garages.)