# Where to spend 3-4hrs after landing in Chicago O'Hare?

Tags: usa, airport-terminals, chicago, ord

I will be landing in Chicago-O'Hare around 7AM. I have a shuttle/bus booked from Terminal 5, departing at 12:40pm, which leaves me with a lot of time (3-4hrs). I am looking for ways to spend this time in the best possible way.

Also, I will be carrying a lot of luggage.

1. Is there any place in the arrivals side of T5 where I could **sit** for those 3-4 hours? Perhaps a seating area, or a reasonably priced lounge, etc?
2. Do I have any option to drop my luggage at a secure place for that duration, so that I could visit the city?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where is your shuttle bus headed to?

Comment: Terminal 5 at O'Hare is the international terminal. At most (all?) US airports, you're required to immediately proceed to Customs & Immigration when you arrive on an international flight; there generally isn't an option to hang around in the arrivals area.

Comment: @Brad I’m taking a shuttle to Purdue University (West Lafayette, IN)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yes,  I’m trying to find options to sit/spend time after immigration and customs.

Comment: I've not been there myself, but have you seen [the map of O'Hare](https://www.flychicago.com/ohare/map/pages/default.aspx)? Also [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4720/2708) deals with napping in O'Hare, perhaps there is useful info there?

Comment: My apologies, I got confused between "airside" and "arrivals".

Comment: Also, if you don't want to sit around for so long, [Reindeer Shuttle](https://www.reindeershuttle.com) offers a 9:15 AM shuttle from O'Hare to Purdue.  (I agree that the 8 AM and 8:40 AM departures offered by other providers are probably cutting it uncomfortably tight.)

Comment: Also related:  [Can I visit Chicago during a 5.5 hour layover in O'Hare?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4780/)

Comment: I came through O'Hare from Mexico at Thanksgiving. We made it through customs very quickly (US citizens with no checked bags, YMMV). You'll be able to find some places to sit somewhere in the terminal, but with "a lot of luggage", you won't want to move around a lot. I'd suggest that your best bet would be to head to the ground transportation area and just hang out. If you're attending Purdue, you'll have lots of friends/roommates who will drag you to Chicago for weekends, so you'll get plenty of time to explore the city.